# Redirect service (302) in Azure, best possible approach?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I need to create a redirector that redirects user to an external domain while retaining the query params and one additional param.

e.g. When a user visits 
`https://contoso.com/redirect?docId=123`, it will redirect the user to 
`https://contoso-v2.com/home?docId=123&token=xxxxxxx`

Once user visits `https://contoso.com/redirect?docId=123`, this endpoint will process the info (from query params) and generate a token that needs to be appended in target URL.

What would be the most efficient and best way in Azure? Writing a simple Azure Web App or is there any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) with [HttpTrigger Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook). With [consumption plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan) the cost would be minimal ([1 million invocations are free in pay-as-you-go plan](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/functions/)).

```
using System.Net;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    var uri = req.RequestUri;
    var updatedUri = ReplaceHostInUri(uri, "contoso-v2.com");

    //return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Original: " + uri + " Updated: " + updatedUri);
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found, updatedUri);
}

private static string ReplaceHostInUri(Uri uri, string newHostName) {
    var builder = new UriBuilder(uri);

    builder.Host = newHostName;
    //Do more trasformations e.g. modify path, add more query string vars

    return builder.Uri.ToString();
}
```